# Efficient strategy for recursive `list.files()` call in R function

Tags: r, performance

I have a folder that will receive raw data from remote stations.
The data structure is mostly controlled by the acquisition date, with a general pattern given by:

`root/unit_mac_address/date/data_here/`

Here's an example of a limited `tree` call for one unit with some days of recording.

```
.
├── 2020-04-03
│   ├── 2020-04-03T11-01-31_capture.txt
│   ├── 2020-04-03T11-32-36_capture.txt
│   ├── 2020-04-03T14-58-43_capture.txt
│   ├── img
│   └── temperatures.csv
...
├── 2020-05-21
│   ├── 2020-05-21T11-10-55_capture.txt
│   ├── img
│   └── temperatures.csv
└── dc:a6:32:2d:b8:62_ip.txt
```

Inside each `img` folder, I have hundreds/thousands of images that are all  timestamped with the datetime of acquisition.

> My goal is to pool the data in `temperatures.csv` from all the units at a `target_date`.

My current approach is the following:

```
# from root dir, get all the temperatures.csv files
all_files <- list.files(pattern = "temperatures.csv",
 full.names = TRUE,
 # do it for all units 
 recursive = TRUE)
# subset the files from the list that contain the target_date
all_files <- all_files[str_detect(all_files, target_date)]
# read and bind into df
df <- lapply(all_files, function(tt) read_csv(tt)) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

I chose to search for `temperatures.csv` because it's not timestamped, but I guess I am also going through all the imgs anyways. I don't think there's a way to limit `list.files()` to a certain level or recursion.

This works but, is it the best way to do it? What can be done to improve performance? Data comes in every day, so there is a growing number of files that the `list.files()` function will have to go through for each of the 10-20 units.

Would it be more efficient if the `temperature.csv` files themselves carried the timestamp (`2020-05-26_temperatures.csv`)? I can ask for timestamps on the `temperatures.csv` files itself (not the current approach) but I feel I should be able to handle this on my side.

Would it be more efficient to only look for dirs that have target_date? and then build the paths so that it's only looking at the first level on each target_date dir? Any hints on doing this appreciated.

Comment: What if you call `list.dirs(recursive = FALSE)` and then paste on `temperatures.csv` and try reading each? That way you don't waste time enumerating all the files.

Comment: Ooooh there's a `list.dirs()`!?!?!? I can try and benchmark that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comment as a good guide, here's the benchmarking for the alternative way to do this.

Here's the gist of the new function

```
all_units <- list.dirs(recursive = FALSE)
# mac address has ":" unlikely in anothed dir
all_units <- all_units[str_detect(all_units, ":")]
all_dirs <- lapply(all_units,
 function(tt) list.dirs(path = tt, recursive = FALSE)) %>%
    unlist()
# there shouldn't be children but
# we paste0 to only get the date folder and not the children of that folder
relevant_dirs <- all_dirs[str_detect(all_dirs, paste0(target_date, "$"))]
all_files <- lapply(relevant_dirs,
 function(tt) 
   list.files(tt, pattern = "temperatures.csv", full.names = TRUE)) %>%
    unlist()
df <- lapply(all_files, function(tt) read_csv(tt)) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

Here's the actual benchmark for a target day with just 2 units getting data, I suspect this difference will only get bigger with time for the recursive option.

```
unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
   read_data 111.76401 124.17692 130.59572 127.84681 133.35566 317.6134  1000
 read_data_2  39.72021  46.58495  50.80255  49.05811  52.01692 141.2126  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really worry about performance you might consider `data.table`, already for its fas `fread` function. Here is an example code:

```r
library(data.table)
target_date <- "2020-04-03"
all_units <- list.dirs(path=".", recursive = FALSE) # or insert your path
all_units <- grep(":..:..:", all_units, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
temp_files <- sapply(all_units,
    function(x) file.path(x, paste0(target_date, "/temperatures.csv")), 
    USE.NAMES = FALSE)
idx <- file.exists(temp_files)
df <- setNames(lapply(temp_files[idx], fread), 
        paste(basename(all_units[idx]), target_date, sep="_"))
rbindlist(df, idcol = "ID")
```

Comment: Thank you, the performance concern is not due to reading, which I always do in a limited way buy finding the actual files to read. For performance reading I might probably switch all the code to vroom package, but it hasn't been necessary so far.

Comment: In my experience performance with `vroom` is only better than with `data.table` when you only work with a subset of rows, so it depends on your use case. It sounds like you can pretty much hardcode the file paths, though, based on your directory structure.

Comment: Exactly. In my experience vroom performance is only better when reading A HUGE file. But the problem in this case is that I have millions of files to sort, and I just only want to read around 10 or 20 medium sized files. So the scaling problem is at the getting the path.

Comment: Are you on a linux/unix/macos system? It would be interesting to see if something like `find . -path '*/2020-04-04/temperatures.csv' -type f` is any faster than the R-based approaches - you could make a `system()` call to get those file paths.

Comment: I am. This is running inside a shinyApp. If performance with this approach turns out to be too taxing I might switch to a system call. Good approach!